# ModelName.real in models of Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have checked one code where in the model its was written an association .

```
has_many :association_name, -> { merge(ModelName.real) }, class_name: ModelName.to_s
```

I would be great if some one explain it.

Comment: `ModelName.real` is not something built into core rails. This is something that you, or a team member, have defined in the code. It may be defined as a `scope`.

Comment: Yes Tom, "real" is a scope name. I forgot to mention it. :)

Comment: Sidenote `ModelName.to_s` does not make a lot of sense here as `ModelName` or `'ModelName'` would suffice. The reason one usually goes with the String version is due to load order since the `String` version will not require a constant to already be defined or cause rails to go and find such a constant and load it. in this case you are already causing rails to check if it is loaded and if not go load it then convert it to a `String` and then back to a constant when the method is called.

Comment: thank you  engineersmnky for explanation

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a method or a scope called `real` on `ModelName` [which gets merged](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge) on the relation query.

[Calling a lambda in a relation applies a kind of default scope](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many-label-Scopes) when calling it, so what happens when you call `MyModel.association_name` is:

```
MyModel.association_name.merge(ModelName.real)
```

Answer (score 0):

Associations may have an optional scope. You should have a method or a scope called `real` within ModelName.

For the class_name option:

> Specify the class name of the association. Use it only if that name
>   can’t be inferred from the association name. So has_many :products
>   will by default be linked to the Product class, but if the real class
>   name is SpecialProduct, you’ll have to specify it with this option.